# How to embed an HTML5 Godot export into a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, godot

I'm going to explain the situation:

These are the files that I end up with after exporting my Godot game in HTML5:
[export files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXaaZ.png)

The most relevant file is *"WYS 0.1.js"*, because is where all the other useful files, like the *.pck* one, are imported and used to execute the application in the HTML file.

In short, if I understand it well, it's a very huge file where the scope is to create a class named "**Engine**" from which is possible to execute some methods like *startEngine()* useful to start the game, following specific configurations that are passed as a parameter of the class.
If you want to check this file here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12JYPd5ItYFFelcJcpIX3eU7kr42Y36up/view?usp=sharing
(Just skip the initial wall of text to see some code that makes sense).

### How the HTML file execute the game?

Simply with a `<script>` tag with **src** attribute pointing to the *"WYS 0.1.js"* path and another `<script>` tag with some *inline JavaScript* that create a new instance of the class **Engine** and deals to correctly load the game and animate the loading of the game (Moving the inline javascript to a separate js file and typing the correct path in the src attribute won't break the execution).

The game, to be correctly executed, needs to be on a **server**. So, I place myself in the export folder with the command line and create a simple server with this Python command: `python -m http.server 8080`, and everything works as it should. Just to be clear.

### React Part:

After created the app with the `npx create-react-app name-app` command, my first attempt was to creat a React Component importing the *"WYS 0.1.js"* and the *inline JS code* moved in a separate file and, from that React Component, use the **Engine** to load and start the game correctly (**Engine** accessible by adding `export` before the `const Engine` declaration). But, what I obtained is a compile error reporting a lot of undefined variables and other stuff like that:

**Line 10:990: Unexpected use of 'self'**

**Line 10:74354: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression**

**Line 10:131511: 'res' is not defined**

**Line 10:115986 :Unexpected use of 'addEventListener'**

As you can see, these errors are located principally in the **Module** variable (the wall of text) and, outside of it, only a certain *"define"* that is placed just under the wall of text.

I also tried to simply add the `<script>` tags in the *index.html* file generated by the `npx create-react-app` command, but it doesn't work at all.

It's not clear to my mind why something is defined in the HTML part and suddenly became undefined when moved in a ReactApp.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me, also because information on this topic is very scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to execute the game in a ReactApp, I don't know if it is the best way to do it but it seems to work. here's my solution:

The godot export files have to be placed in the **public** folder, **NOT IN A SUB FOLDER IN THE PUBLIC FOLDER**, the main JS file, *"WYS 0.1.js"*, has to be in the same directory of the *index.html*. Some files can be exluded, but the *"WYS 0.1.js"*, *.wasm* and the *.pck* have to be in that directory and, even if everything seems to work without it, I would put the *.worklet.js* as well.

That said, to execute the game you need to copy the `<script>` tags in the *"WYS 0.1.js"* and insert them into the *index.html* file, generated by `npx create-react-app name-app` command. In truth, in this state you need to copy the entire `<body>` tag and put it into the *index.html*, because the **inline JavaScript code**, in the second `<script>` tag, needs to access to some elements in the `<body>` to animate the loading and to execute the game in the `<canvas>` tag.

### Therefore, we'll jump to the reusability part now.

To enclose the execution of the game in a **ReactComponent** that i can render at any moment and place I want I, firstly, moved the inline JS in a separate JS file, *init_godot_game.js*, and imported it in the same `<script>` tag putting the path in the **src** attribute. Then, i changed a bit this code moved in this new JS file, just putting it in a function that i can call: *init_game()*, for example.

Now, for the React part, just create a new component and make it return all the body content of the *"WYS 0.1.html"* file that we pasted in the *index.html*, content that now you can remove from there (before starting it, you have to change a bit this code so that it can fit the JSX syntax).

From here, to execute the game you just have to add a new `<script>` tag int the body with calling the *init_game()* function, like this:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript"
script.innerHTML = "init_game()"
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

You can put this piece of code in a `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` or in a function that you can invoke when you want. I tried to expose the *init_game()* function with an export and to import it in the ReactComponent with: `import { init_game } from "path"`, but it's not possible to import stuff outside the **src** folder. Moving the *init_godot_game.js* in the **src** folder will cause similar errors of my previous approach. **It appears that these files must be in the same path as *index.html***.

Anyway, these part of the reusability and even of how you want to load the game, is pretty up to you. You can customize it as you wish, if I get it well, only a few things are needed:

- you have to execute the method *engine.startGame()*, in the JS file
  that deals to load and initialize the game, in my example:
  *init_godot_game()*. The rest is marginal.
- And in the ReactApp, in the component or wherever you want to run
  your game, must be the `<canvas id="canvas">` tag, because is what the
  main JS file wants as the container of the the game.

Tell me what you think about it, especially if you have better solutions :)